# An ODE $u'(s) + p(s)u(s) + q(s)=0$ that holds only for almost all $s$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Suppose that the following ODE holds for almost all $s \in [0,K)$ where $K$ may be infinite:
$$\frac{du(s)}{ds} + p(s)u(s) + q(s) = 0.$$

This is a nonhomogeneous first order linear ODE. Do we still get a solution $u(s)$ explicitly given in terms of $p$ and $q$ using integrating factor? Does it make sense to think of an ODE as holding only a.e.?

I want to know if the theory still carries forward. For example if instead of the ODE we had $\leq 0$ instead of $=0$, can we still compare the solution of this differential inequality to the solution of the corresponding ODE?

Comment: Do we still get a solution u(s) explicitly given in terms of p and q using integrating factor? 
we always can solve the D.E using integrating factors however, the difficultly is hide behind on what variable the D.E depends on '$x$',$'y'$ or both and how can find the integrating factor. Does it make sense to think of an ODE as holding only a.e.?   I think if you seeking a solution on a set $A$ of a measure zero, the answer is yes. If instead of the ODE we had ≤0 instead of =0..? this looks like you optimize a function $u$ with certain constrains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it make sense to think of an ODE as holding only a.e.?

Yes, it does, and the theory (existence/uniqueness) still carries forward, provided the concept of *solution* is correctly defined. A solution of such ODE means an [absolutely continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) for which the equality holds a.e. (Every absolutely continuous function is differentiable a.e.)

Absolute continuity is precisely what one needs to use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations), i.e., to recover a function from its derivative. When you use an integrating factor $I$, the key step is passing from $(Iu)'=-Iq$ to $Iu=-\int Iq+C$. Here $I$ is absolutely continuous by construction (it's an antiderivative of an integrable function). Hence $Iu$ is absolutely continuous, and thus can be recovered from the values of its derivative at a.e. point.

The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which satisfies $u'=0$ a.e., shows  what would go  wrong if we neglected absolute continuity.